# ng:areq error (angularjs), only in Internet Explorer Edge

Tags: html, angularjs, controller

I've got the following Error: `ERROR: [ng:areq]` when I want to start the `index.html`. This error only occurs in the Internet Explorer edge and not in Chrome.
Here is a code snippet from creating the controller:

app.js:

```
var jsWorkshopApp = angular.module('jsWorkshopApp', []);

jsWorkshopApp.run(function ($rootScope, $templateCache) {

    // prevent caching
    $rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function () {
        $templateCache.removeAll();
    });
});
```

controller.js:

```
if (!jsWorkshopApp) {
    var jsWorkshopApp = angular.module('jsWorkshopApp', []);
}


jsWorkshopApp.controller('JsWorkshopCtrl', function ($scope, $http, myService) {
    $scope.chapters;
...
..
});
```

I've got no idea, what is wrong. I even delete the `[]` but then it raises another error and in chrome it doesn't work either.

Comment: Did you get a solution for this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

It may be an ordering problem. Have you added reference to script files in order of as :

The app.js should be added before controller.js

If above is correct then please check you have no typo while assigning ng-controller value in view. The cotnroller name is case sensitive.